# Changing x-Axis Values of graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

My graph has on the y-axis numerical values of my data which is the level of depression and on the the x-axis I have order (numbers from 1-40 because I have 40 observations) But these are in fact quarters as my data is quarterly (2008-2013). So I would like to change the x-axis from an order of 1-40 to Year and Quarter (e.g. 2008 Q1,2008 Q2,..). I am however not sure how I can do that. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your Help!

Comment: Hey David, can you add your current code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make another column in your dataframe/matrix with the Year and Quarter.
Then set that column as the x-axis.
Something like this

```
for(i in 1:40){
  if(i %% 4 == 0)
    data$quarter[i] <- paste(as.integer((i - 1) / 4) + 2008, " Q4", sep = "")
  else
    data$quarter[i] <- paste(as.integer((i - 1) / 4) + 2008, " Q", i %% 4, sep = "")
}
```

This is of course assuming that they are in order. If they are not in order or you have overlap, you may have to just make it manually.

Comment: Hey I just realised that I need to difference it all NOT with respect to the first value but with respect to the the 27th observations which is Q3 2010. )my data actually is from 2004 to 2013 not 2008 to 2013 sorry). DO you know how I would go about that? Thank you.

Comment: Are they still in order? Do the dates start with 2004 Q1?
If so, just change the 2008 above to 2004 and you should be all set.